# Origin does not have permission to use geolocation service

Tags: geolocation, location

please help me i am so stuck now. my purpose is to access user location using navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition API of browser. it is working fine in window andriod accept Mac OS and IOS . the message i receive from this is :
Origin does not have permission to use geolocation service

i do a lot of research. result is some said it must https and also go to settings privacy. i follow it and still now working.

here is my code

```
function onRequestGeolocation() {
    if (!navigator.geolocation) return toast.error("Browser not support geolocation ! ")

    return navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position: GeolocationPosition) => {
        const { coords } = position;
        return { latitude: coords.latitude, longitude: coords.longitude }

    }, onError, options)
}

function onError(err: GeolocationPositionError) {
    toast.error(err.message)
}
```

Another research here : https://developer.chrome.com/blog/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only/#does-my-whole-web-app-need-https

but i dont know how to remove those http not secure  can anyone help me

If you can please write me some code that work on both window and IOS. thank you

Comment: oh my G. im an idiot . i request to an url that using http now i change to https and it work .